# how to call a method of a class from another appDomain

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

my application want to call a method of a class that is from another AppDomain.

```
       AppDomain env = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
            "test",
            null,
            new AppDomainSetup() { ApplicationName = "test" }
            );

        Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("d:\\testenv1\\test2.dll");
        //env.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(env_AssemblyResolve);
        env.Load(a.FullName);

        ObjectHandle o = env.CreateInstance(a.FullName, "Test2.Class1");
```

now i have the object handle of the Test2.Class1, but i have no idea how to invode the "action" method of the Class1 class.

the "action" method likes this:

```
    public void action()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName + " ok");
    }
```

i tried to use o.unwrap() method to get the reference of the object, but it seems the object has been transferred into the current domain, so the output of the "action" method prints the current domain name.

Comment: Why do I get the `FileNotFoundException` while executing you code? The assembly can't be load to the test appdomain. Does it has a strong name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark the object that you want to use for cross appdomain communication as [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx).