# How do I call a method in another AppDomain

Tags: c#, remoting, appdomain

How do I call a method on an object I created in another AppDomain? I would like to avoid using `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` because that would require that I reference the DLL I want to operate on.

```
public static void Main() {
    // Create domain
    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Foo");

    // Load assembly
    domain.Load("C:\\Foo.dll");

    // Create instance of class
    System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle inst
        = domain.CreateInstance("C:\\Foo.dll", "MyNamespace.MyClass");

    // Call method -- How can I do this ???
    object result = inst.PleaseCallMethod("MyMethod", "param1", 42, "p3", null);
}
```

And in `Foo.dll` I would have:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    public class MyClass {
        public string MyMethod(string p1, int p2, string p3, string p4) {
            return "...";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, how would I call a static method, without first creating an instance of the (possibly static) class that contains it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call a method of a class from another appDomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843421/how-to-call-a-method-of-a-class-from-another-appdomain)

Comment: @NathanA Indeed, that other question seems similar. Could you please then provide an answer to the question you linked to ? Currently, the best answer is "Use MarshalByRefObject. cool! i did not expect it to be this easy, haha~~~", which is rather unhelpful to say the least. My object does implement `MarshallByRef` but I still don't know how to write `inst.PleaseCallMethod(name, params)`.

Comment: Remoteing is considered a ["legacy technology"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/72x4h507(v=vs.100).aspx), can you explain more about your setup and what you are trying to do. Perhaps we can point you to the right thing to use.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have a method in a .dll that crashes when called by another piece of software, but runs smoothly when I call it myself in a standalone executable, so my guess is that the other piece of software loaded some "crap" along with the .dll, which makes it crash, and I thought running the method in a separate appdomain would isolate it from that "crap". I got something quick & dirty working with `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` but I wondered how I would do that with just `CreateInstance`.

Answer (score 5):

You can call:

```
domain.DoCallBack(() => Console.WriteLine("DoCallBack: {0}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName));
```

but that requires that the assembly running the code to be loaded into the new appdomain.

If your new appdomain has a different base path and/or requires an assembly that can't be resolved by the runtime in the new appdomain you may need to create an isolated entry assembly that you invoke in DoCallBack and from this one load the assemblies from their desired location.