# Setup of the project was unable to open database on another machine. my project is in c# windows application with sqlite database connection

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, deployment

I have inserted app.config file in my project.
Please help me out to overcome from this problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RConnString" connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Pathology lab\Pathology lab\bin\Debug\Pathology.sqlite"
      providerName="System.Data.Sqlite" />
    <add name="Pathology_lab.Properties.Settings.PathologyConnectionString"
      connectionString="data source=&quot;C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Pathology lab\Pathology lab\bin\Debug\Pathology.sqlite;"
      providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
    <add name="screen_shot.Properties.Settings.PathorecordConnectionString"
      connectionString="data source=&quot;C:\Users\user\Desktop\screen shot\screen shot\bin\Debug\Pathorecord.db&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this connection string

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 1):

try to write connection string in |DataDirectory|/Databasename.db
And call App.domain () method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843421/how-to-call-a-method-of-a-class-from-another-appdomain 
This link mite help you